# androidplot does not draw when range boundary set to AUTO

Tags: android, androidplot

I have this method that setups up my plot to graph some realtime data against time

```
private static void setupPlot(XYPlot dsPlot, TimeBasedXYSeries series, int color) {

    dsPlot.setUserDomainOrigin(0);
    dsPlot.setUserRangeOrigin(0);
    dsPlot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 15, BoundaryMode.AUTO);

    dsPlot.addSeries(series,
            new LineAndPointFormatter(
                 color, null, null, null));


    dsPlot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 10);
    dsPlot.setTicksPerDomainLabel(5);
    dsPlot.setDomainLabel("Time");
    dsPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().pack();

    dsPlot.setRangeStepValue(5);
    dsPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);

    dsPlot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));

    dsPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new TimeLineFormat());
    dsPlot.setMarkupEnabled(true);
}
```

when I use

```
    dsPlot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 15, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

it works but I do not want to use FIXED as I do not know the boundaries ahead of time.

`BoundaryMode.AUTO` or `BoundaryMode.GROW` does not seem to be plotting anything.

Any ideas as to how I can let the range boundaries auto adjust based on data?

I am using androidplot 0.6.1 as that appears to be the last version that has a jar output. Due to my project setup, I am not able to use aar file libraries.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, but it's really hard to say for a version as old as 0.6.1.  in fact i'd be surprised if there's anyone around that will be able to give a definitive answer.  i know it's not the answer you're looking for but what about including the latest version of androidplot as a submodule (as source) instead of as a jar or aar?

Comment: Ok thank Nick. I will try including androidplot as submodule with latest source and see what happens. I will report back.